# Using JPA is empty in "or" statement

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm building a JPA query using spring-data-jpa's `@Query` annotation and can't get it working. I have two classes class (setters/getters stripped)

```
public class Article {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderColumn(name = "review_index")
    private List<Review> reviews;
}
```

and

```
public class Review {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "review_state")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ReviewState state;  // simple enum
}
```

**What it should do**: the query should return all `Article` with either *no* review at all or with the `Review` with the highest index in the collection having the state `PASSED`.

```
@Query("select distinct article from Article article "
    + "left outer join article.reviews r " // outer join to include articles without review
    // be sure to be either unreviewed or passed the review
    + "where (article.reviews is empty or article.reviews[maxindex(article.reviews)].state = 'PASSED'))"
```

**What it actually does:** The problem is that `Articles` with no review at all get excluded from the result. It seems as if `article.reviews is empty` isn't honoured at all. On a sidenote: `is empty` works if the second part of the `or` statement is left out.

Comment: Why not just r.state = 'PASSED'. This would result in all articles without a review or a passed review.

Comment: Because it's important that only the review with the highest index in the collection counts.

Comment: Can you try: "where r.state = 'PASSED' and r.id = article.reviews[maxindex(article.reviews)].id" (not sure to be honest)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this doesn't work either.

Comment: I have not the time right now to create a simple test setup. The problem is most likely that the right hand side of the or create a normal join in the generated sql. So try to seperate this part in a subselect.

Comment: Don't worry. Will try to separate the right part into a subselect, thank you!

Comment: @mh-dev I replaced the right hand side of the "or" with a subquery reading `or exists(select article2 from Article article2 where article.id = article2.id and article2.reviews[maxindex(article2.reviews)].state = 'PASSED')`. This solved the issue and should be the correct answer. Feel free to add it as answer, I'll accept it then. Thanks a lot for the push in the right direction!

Comment: Perfect I added it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer extracted from the Comments:

The core issue was related to the implicit join (not left join) of the path navigation "article.reviews".
This can be bypassed with a dedicated sub select for this part.

```
select distinct article 
from Article article
left outer join article.reviews r 
where article.reviews is empty or 
    exists(
        select subArticle 
        from Article subArticle 
        where article.id = subArticle.id 
        and subArticle.reviews[maxindex(subArticle.reviews)].state = 'PASSED'
    )
```